# How to filter a list in an object AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, filter

i have an object like this :

```
var obj ={
name:'vince',
list:[{area:'bxl'},
      {area:'fra'},
      {area:'ita'},
      {shop[
            {name:'shop1'},
            {name:'shop2}]}]}
```

how can i filter the list object contained in obj?
I tried a lot of solutions but no way.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example filters the `list` in `obj`. Returns all objects with `area === 'fra'`

```
obj.list = obj.list.filter(function (item) {
    if (item.area === 'fra') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter a list like this:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
list.filter(function(element) {
    return element < 3; // return true or false
});
```

Inside the passed function, you return a boolean depending on the current element. In this case I check each element if it is smaller than 3.

The result is `[1, 2]`.

So in your case you can do this:

```
obj.list.filter(function(element) {
    // Do your check and return boolean
});
```